# Oracle sql update with table join giving error

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am running the following Oracle update statement and getting error:

ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
UPDATE Maximo.laborcraftrate lcr
SET lcr.controlaccount = (SELECT c.mxrcontrolaccount
                     FROM maximo.contract c
                     WHERE lcr.contractnum = c.CONTRACTNUM)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT controlaccount
              FROM maximo.contract c
              WHERE lcr.contractnum = c.contractnum);
```

Does anyone know how to limit the subquery?

EDIT:

Here is a select statement showing the join between the tables. What I am trying to do is update the a.controlaccount with b.controlaccount under these conditions:

```
CRAFT   CONTRACTNUM CONTROLACCOUNT  MXRCONTROLACCOUNT
TR-CHNDI    TR-GENERAL      01-3010-72515
TR-CHNDP             TR-GENERAL     01-3010-72515
TR-CHNDI             TR-GENERAL     01-3010-72515
TR-CHNDI             TR-GENERAL     01-3010-72515
TR-CHNDP             TR-GENERAL     01-3010-72515
TR-FENI          TR-GENERAL     01-3010-72515
```

```
select a.craft,a.contractnum,a.controlaccount,b.mxrcontrolaccount
from maximo.laborcraftrate a
left join maximo.contract b on a.contractnum = b.contractnum
where a.contractnum is not null
```

Comment: You can do "(SELECT MAX(c.mxrcontrolaccount)". But the question is: What do you want if there are different values?

Comment: Why  `WHERE c.contractnum = c.CONTRACTNUM`? Maybe `WHERE c.contractnum = lcr.CONTRACTNUM`

Comment: I don't understand how there can be multiple values because each laborcraftrate only has one contract, but one contract can have many laborcraftrates, so I'm concerned using max will give incorrect results

Comment: @Tatiana - that was a typo in the question, I have edited, but the problem is the same

Comment: Run `select contractnum, count(*) from maximo.contract group by contractnum having count(*) > 1`, which will give you the rows that are potentially returning more than one row in your subquery.  Then you'll have to figure out if there is a problem with your data or your query.

Comment: @sstan there are some contracts with multiple lines, but none of the contracts I am interested in

Comment: Try this one then: `select contractnum, count(*) from maximo.contract a where exists (select null from Maximo.laborcraftrate b where b.contractnum = a.contractnum) group by contractnum having count(*) > 1`.  Do you still get rows then?  If so, you have a problem.

Comment: @sstan yep I get one result with 2 rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What don't you understand about the error?  The subquery is returning more than one row.

One simple solution is to just add `and rownum = 1`:

```
UPDATE Maximo.laborcraftrate lcr
    SET lcr.controlaccount = (SELECT c.mxrcontrolaccount
                              FROM maximo.contract c
                              WHERE lcr.contractnum = c.CONTRACTNUM AND rownum = 1
                             )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT controlaccount
                  FROM maximo.contract c
                  WHERE lcr.contractnum = c.contractnum);
```

Or to use an aggregation function.  Both of these guarantee at most one row.  However, this problem is not necessarily amenable to simple fixes.  Often there is a logical issue.

Comment: running queries from comments above to check for duplicates helped me resolve this issue